# MySQL concurrent update on a very large table

Tags: mysql, concurrency

I have a MySQL table with about 8 gazillion rows. I want to run an update query for each row, updating one column. I'm finding that running a basic `UPDATE` query causes, "ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded". When creating a stored procedure to run the update in chunks, the time I estimate for the query to complete is in days. Can I use concurrency to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an `UPDATE` query on a MySQL table can be completed faster by running queries concurrently over multiple MySQL connections. Here's an example:

Create a test table with a debug log table (*more on this later*):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id`                INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `foo`               VARCHAR(8),
    `bar`               VARCHAR(8),
    `baz`               VARCHAR(17),
    `updated_by_worker` INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE `test_debug_log` (
    `id`            INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `worker_number` INT,
    `total_workers` INT,
    `value`         VARCHAR(255),
    `time`          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

Create a procedure to fill the test table with one million rows of dummy data:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_data_into_test_table`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `iterator`       INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `rows_to_insert` INT DEFAULT 1000000;

    START TRANSACTION;

    WHILE `iterator` < `rows_to_insert` DO
        INSERT INTO `test` (`foo`, `bar`)
        VALUES (
            LEFT(UUID(), 8),
            LEFT(UUID(), 8)
        );

        SET `iterator` = `iterator` + 1;
    END WHILE;

    COMMIT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Run the procedure:

```sql
CALL `insert_data_into_test_table`();
```

Create a procedure that creates a "worker" which runs the `UPDATE` query on a chunk of the table. You should know in advance how many workers there will be with their own MySQL connection.

The procedure automatically divides up the table into ranges that each worker will process. Further, inside that range, the worker will only process `max_rows_to_process_per_loop` rows at a time in order to avoid memory issues. This variable should be tuned depending on your system resources.

For debugging purposes, variables are logged to the `test_debug_log` table. You can turn this off by setting `log_debug_messages` to `FALSE`.

The `UPDATE` query in the procedure concatenates the `foo` and `bar` columns with a hyphen in between, and sets `baz` as the resulting value.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `concurrently_update_test_table`(IN `worker_number` INT, IN `total_workers` INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE `log_debug_messages`           BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE;
    DECLARE `total_rows_in_table`          INT     DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `rows_processed`               INT     DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `total_rows_to_process`        INT     DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `starting_offset`              INT     DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `max_rows_to_process_per_loop` INT     DEFAULT 100000;
    DECLARE `batch_size`                   INT     DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `current_offset`               INT     DEFAULT 0;

    SET `total_rows_in_table`   = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`);
    SET `total_rows_to_process` = CEIL(`total_rows_in_table` / `total_workers`);
    SET `starting_offset`       = (`worker_number` - 1) * `total_rows_to_process`;

    -- Set limit on rows to process per loop to avoid memory issues.
    IF `total_rows_to_process` > `max_rows_to_process_per_loop` THEN
        SET `batch_size` = `max_rows_to_process_per_loop`;
    ELSE
        SET `batch_size` = `total_rows_to_process`;
    END IF;

    SET `current_offset` = `starting_offset`;

    IF `log_debug_messages` THEN
        INSERT INTO `test_debug_log` (`worker_number`, `total_workers`, `value`) VALUES (
            `worker_number`,
            `total_workers`,
            '--- START OF WORKER ---'
        );

        INSERT INTO `test_debug_log` (`worker_number`, `total_workers`, `value`) VALUES (
            `worker_number`,
            `total_workers`,
            CONCAT_WS(
                ', ',
                CONCAT('total_rows_in_table: ', `total_rows_in_table`),
                CONCAT('rows_processed: ', `rows_processed`),
                CONCAT('total_rows_to_process: ', `total_rows_to_process`),
                CONCAT('starting_offset: ', `starting_offset`),
                CONCAT('max_rows_to_process_per_loop: ', `max_rows_to_process_per_loop`),
                CONCAT('batch_size: ', `batch_size`),
                CONCAT('current_offset: ', `current_offset`)
            )
        );
    END IF;

    WHILE `rows_processed` < `total_rows_to_process` DO
        IF `log_debug_messages` THEN
            INSERT INTO `test_debug_log` (`worker_number`, `total_workers`, `value`) VALUES (
                `worker_number`,
                `total_workers`,
                '--- BEGINNING OF LOOP ---'
            );

            INSERT INTO `test_debug_log` (`worker_number`, `total_workers`, `value`) VALUES (
                `worker_number`,
                `total_workers`,
                CONCAT_WS(
                    ', ',
                    CONCAT('rows_processed: ', `rows_processed`),
                    CONCAT('total_rows_to_process: ', `total_rows_to_process`)
                )
            );
        END IF;

        -- If last loop, don't exceed `total_rows_to_process`.
        IF `current_offset` + `batch_size` > `starting_offset` + `total_rows_to_process` THEN
            IF `log_debug_messages` THEN
                INSERT INTO `test_debug_log` (`worker_number`, `total_workers`, `value`) VALUES (
                    `worker_number`,
                    `total_workers`,
                    'Last Loop'
                );
            END IF;

            SET `batch_size` = (`starting_offset` + `total_rows_to_process`) - `current_offset`;
        END IF;

        IF `log_debug_messages` THEN
            INSERT INTO `test_debug_log` (`worker_number`, `total_workers`, `value`) VALUES (
                `worker_number`,
                `total_workers`,
                CONCAT_WS(
                    ', ',
                    CONCAT('current_offset: ', `current_offset`),
                    CONCAT('batch_size: ', `batch_size`)
                )
            );
        END IF;

        START TRANSACTION;

        WITH `test_rows_to_update` AS 
        (
            SELECT `id`
            FROM `test`
            ORDER BY `id`
            LIMIT `current_offset`, `batch_size`
        )
        UPDATE `test`
        JOIN `test_rows_to_update` ON `test`.`id` = `test_rows_to_update`.`id`
        SET
            `test`.`baz` = CONCAT_WS('-', `test`.`foo`, `test`.`bar`),
            `test`.`updated_by_worker` = `worker_number`
        WHERE `test`.`id` = `test_rows_to_update`.`id`;

        COMMIT;

        SET `rows_processed` = `rows_processed` + `batch_size`;
        SET `current_offset` = `current_offset` + `batch_size`;

        IF `log_debug_messages` THEN
            INSERT INTO `test_debug_log` (`worker_number`, `total_workers`, `value`) VALUES (
                `worker_number`,
                `total_workers`,
                '--- END OF LOOP ---'
            );
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    IF `log_debug_messages` THEN
        INSERT INTO `test_debug_log` (`worker_number`, `total_workers`, `value`) VALUES (
            `worker_number`,
            `total_workers`,
            '--- END OF WORKER ---'
        );
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Call the procedure in separate MySQL connections:

```sql
-- MySQL connection 1:
CALL `concurrently_update_test_table`(1, 5);

-- MySQL connection 2:
CALL `concurrently_update_test_table`(2, 5);

-- MySQL connection 3:
CALL `concurrently_update_test_table`(3, 5);

-- MySQL connection 4:
CALL `concurrently_update_test_table`(4, 5);

-- MySQL connection 5:
CALL `concurrently_update_test_table`(5, 5);
```

If you want to compare how long the queries take to complete *consecutively* on a single MySQL connection:

```sql
SET @start_time = NOW();

CALL `concurrently_update_test_table`(1, 5);
CALL `concurrently_update_test_table`(2, 5);
CALL `concurrently_update_test_table`(3, 5);
CALL `concurrently_update_test_table`(4, 5);
CALL `concurrently_update_test_table`(5, 5);

SET @end_time = NOW();

SELECT CONCAT(
   FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(@end_time, @start_time)) / 24), ' days, ',
   MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(@end_time, @start_time)), 24), ' hours, ',
   MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(@end_time, @start_time)), ' minutes, ',
   SECOND(TIMEDIFF(@end_time, @start_time)), ' seconds'
) AS `total_time`;
```

To reset everything:

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE `test`;
ALTER TABLE `test` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
TRUNCATE TABLE `test_debug_log`;
ALTER TABLE `test_debug_log` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
CALL `insert_data_into_test_table`();
```

To delete everything:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE `insert_data_into_test_table`;
DROP PROCEDURE `concurrently_update_test_table`;
DROP TABLE `test`;
DROP TABLE `test_debug_log`;
```

A Python script to run a benchmark comparing consecutive MySQL queries to concurrent MySQL queries:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import mysql.connector
import time

db_config = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "3306",
    "database": "my_database",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "password"
}

total_workers = 5
queries = []

for worker_number in range(1, total_workers + 1):
    queries.append(f'CALL `concurrently_update_test_table`({worker_number}, {total_workers});')

def run_query(query):
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print(f"Error occurred during query execution: {err}")
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

# Reset tables.
print("Resetting tables...")
run_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `test`;")
run_query("ALTER TABLE `test` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;")
run_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `test_debug_log`;")
run_query("ALTER TABLE `test_debug_log` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;")
run_query("CALL `insert_data_into_test_table`();")
print("Done.\n")

# Time consecutive queries.
print("Starting consecutive queries...")
consecutive_start_time = time.time()

for query in queries:
    run_query(query)

consecutive_end_time = time.time()
consecutive_elapsed_time = round(consecutive_end_time - consecutive_start_time, 2)

print("Done.")
print("Consecutive queries elapsed time: " + str(consecutive_elapsed_time) + " seconds\n")

# Time concurrent queries.
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    print("Starting concurrent queries...")
    concurrent_start_time = time.time()

    futures = [executor.submit(run_query, query) for query in queries]
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

    concurrent_end_time = time.time()
    concurrent_elapsed_time = round(concurrent_end_time - concurrent_start_time, 2)

    print("Done.")
    print("Concurrent queries elapsed time: " + str(concurrent_elapsed_time) + " seconds\n")

# Compare both.
if concurrent_elapsed_time == consecutive_elapsed_time:
    print("The concurrent queries took exactly as long as the consecutive queries.")
else:
    try:
        change =  consecutive_elapsed_time - concurrent_elapsed_time
        percentage_change = (change / concurrent_elapsed_time) * 100
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        percentage_change = 0

    if percentage_change > 0:
        speed = "faster"
    else:
        speed = "slower"

    print(f"Concurrent queries are {percentage_change:.2f}% {speed}")
```

Results from my machine:

```bash
Starting consecutive queries...
Done.
Consecutive queries elapsed time: 31.96 seconds

Starting concurrent queries...
Done.
Concurrent queries elapsed time: 9.02 seconds

The concurrent queries are 254.32% faster
```

If "*Error Code: 1317. Query execution was interrupted*" occurs, executing these statements before calling `concurrently_update_test_table` seems to help:

```sql
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000;
```

For more options see:

[15.7.2.1 Transaction Isolation Levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted)

[15.14 InnoDB Startup Options and System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout)

If "*Error Code: 1206. The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size*" occurs, increasing the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` in `my.ini` (taking into account system resources) seems to help:

```bash
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4096M
```